# SSH: debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22

Tags: github, ssh

Why, when debugging SSH, do I get a private IP being used for `github.com`?

E.g. using `ssh -T`

```
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.112] port 22.
```

Comment: That isn't a private IP.

Comment: Doh! Of course, I'm thinking of `192.168.x.x`.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a private IP address.  The only private IPs in the 192.0.0.0/8 block have a second byte of 168 (i.e., 192.168.0.0/16), not 30.